# jenkins connect ssh slave tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified

Tags: bash, jenkins, amazon-ec2, ssh

I am trying to connect my Jenkins master to a slave node over SSH. I have verified I am able to SSH between the master and slave nodes from a terminal. I have provided Jenkins with the key and password for the slave node. My Host Key Verification Strategy is `Manually Trusted key verification Strategy. When I select`Launch Agent`, I see the following error.

```
[11/22/17 09:40:39] [SSH] Opening SSH connection to ec2-**-**-**-**.*********.compute.amazonaws.com:22.
[11/22/17 09:40:39] [SSH] SSH host key matches key seen previously for this host. Connection will be allowed.
[11/22/17 09:40:39] [SSH] Authentication successful.
SSH connection reports a garbage before a command execution.
Check your .bashrc, .profile, and so on to make sure it is quiet.
The received junk text is as follows:
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified

null
[11/22/17 09:40:39] Launch failed - cleaning up connection
[11/22/17 09:40:39] [SSH] Connection closed.
```

The Jenkins logs on the master node show the following.

```
    Nov 22, 2017 10:18:57 AM hudson.plugins.sshslaves.verifiers.TrileadVersionSupportManager getTrileadSupport
WARNING: Could not create Trilead support class. Using legacy Trilead features
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hudson.plugins.sshslaves.verifiers.JenkinsTrilead9VersionSupport
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:560)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.verifiers.TrileadVersionSupportManager.createVersion9Instance(TrileadVersionSupportManager.java:51)
    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.verifiers.TrileadVersionSupportManager.getTrileadSupport(TrileadVersionSupportManager.java:32)
    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.verifiers.SshHostKeyVerificationStrategy.getPreferredKeyAlgorithms(SshHostKeyVerificationStrategy.java:68)
    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.verifiers.ManuallyTrustedKeyVerificationStrategy.getPreferredKeyAlgorithms(ManuallyTrustedKeyVerificationStrategy.java:105)
    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher$2.call(SSHLauncher.java:797)
    at hudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher$2.call(SSHLauncher.java:793)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

[11/22/17 10:18:58] SSH Launch of DevOperations on ec2-**-**-**-**.*********.compute.amazonaws.com failed in 641 ms
```

It appears to be an issue with the `.bashrc`, but I do not know what to edit in the `.bashrc` file to make it quiet.

How can I get the SSH launch to succeed?

Jenkins: ver. 2.91

Master node: Amazon Linux AMI release 2017.09

Slave Node: Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0):

I found the fix. On the Slave box, I had to edit the `~/.bashrc` to remove where it was setting colours running:

```
magenta=$(tput setaf 4)
reset=$(tput sgr0)
```

Removing this fixed the issue